# Allowance approval and TransferFrom

Tags: solidity, transferfrom

Imagine someone I don’t know give me approval to spend their token , so now what I need is how to see those that has approved my wallet address to spend(allowance) their tokens

Comment: You need to index/scan the blockchain and look for Approval events where ur address is the event. possible but not doable.

Comment: Thanks for the idea , now that it seems pot it not doable, what can I do? 

Like this page, it show the lists of all the smart contract that a wallet have given access to, https://bscscan.com/tokenapprovalchecker
But what I need is how to see those that give access to my wallet

Comment: Yes you need the other way of what this page does. the other way is much harder to do. Therefore probably no one did it.

Comment: You can do that for couple of tokens that has value. But you will never be able to do that for every token that exists. The are thousands or thousands useless no value tokens

Comment: You can do that for couple of tokens that has value. But you will never be able to do that for every token that exists

This is exactly what I need, I should be able to do it for some tokens that has values. 

Please how do I make it possible for the tokens that has value, this will be much more appreciated

Comment: I have no code. As I said you need to scan/index the blockchain and looks for events. If you are doing it for a couple of coins then it is possible. Try „the graph protocol“ the best way to index the blockchain and look for events

Answer (score 0):

My tool [Revoke.cash](https://revoke.cash) checks for all the allowances that you gave to someone else, but the same process can be used to check for the allowances that someone gave to you by changing a few values.

The code for Revoke is [open source](https://github.com/RevokeCash/revoke.cash) so it can be forked and updated for this use case. Someone in the past created a tool like this that was forked from Revoke: https://github.com/yashnaman/revoke.cash. It's from 2+ years ago, so it might not be completely up to date, but with the source code of the latest Revoke.cash and the outdated "reverse Revoke.cash" fork, you should be able to get pretty far.